# Casting double to string

Tags: c#, excel, casting, double

I am trying to get data from excel file. I managed to get the data except for 1 column which is set as double not string. I am trying to get the value of this column with this code:

```
NET_DEPOSIT = x.Field<string>("NET_DEPOSIT"),
```

using the below code will give an error to use a nullable type.

```
x.Field<double>("NET_DEPOSIT").ToString()
```

NET_DEPOSIT is set as string in the database and set as double in the excel sheet.

however I am getting Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'." error

Any help please ?

Comment: seriously, you can't spot the issue here? perhaps use `<double>` instead of `<string>`... it really couldn't be a more useful exception message if it tried

Comment: @musefan DOES NOT WORK !

Comment: @MarkFenech: Why not?

Comment: Because Net_Deposit is set as double in the excel and set as string in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use:

```
   NET_DEPOSIT = Convert.ToString(x.Field<double?>("NET_DEPOSIT")),
```

This is because of nullable types and therefore use the ? notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that : 
    `x.Field<Double>("NET_DEPOSIT").ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

If the field is a double I should think you would need to do something like this:

```
NET_DEPOSIT = x.Field<double>("NET_DEPOSIT"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x.Field("NET_DEPOSIT").ToString("0.000000")
```